# Specify expiration for Parse Session token

Tags: security, session, parse-platform

Is there any way to change the expiration of a Parse session token to something other than 1 year or no-expiry?

Ideally I'd like to change the expiry to something like 14 days.

Comment: I guess with Parse's dissolution this is a moot point.